# In a Matlab gui how do you execute a .m file returned as a result of uigetfile?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a Matlab gui with a button that calls uigetfile. The user picks the file they want to run, and then my gui should execute that .m file, returning the results to the gui for further processing.

Uigetfile works great and I can capture the filename and filepath:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.m', 'Pick a .m file');
```

When I try to execute the filename:

```
total = [pathname filename];

% copy into current directory since files user selects could be in other directories
copyfile(total);   

% attempt to execute .m function the user selected
[a, b] = filename();
```

I get this error:

```
Indexing cannot yield multiple results.
```

My research suggests this is because I have a variable named "filename" so Matlab thinks I'm trying to use the variable, rather than call the function. This makes good sense to me, but then I don't know how to get around this!

How can I call the result of uigetfile without it also being a variable? Or, how else can I run a .m file selected by the user in a gui?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the same folder as the m.file, you can enclose the whole uigetfile call to the **run** function to execute it:

```
run(uigetfile('*.m', 'Pick a .m file'))
```

This way you avoid the naming conflict with you previously defined *filename* variable and call the result of uigetfile without storing its output. However if you want to run the script from a different folder, I'd suggest store the results of uigetfile with different names:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.m', 'Pick a .m file');
run([filepath filename])
```

This enables you to run the mfile without the need to copy it to the current folder, and still avoids any conflicts with your previously defined variable.

Comment: Hmm, I like the simplicity... but two questions. 1) You can't do a check on the output of uigetfile to see if its valid this way? In other words if the user clicks cancel it produces an error since it can't run without a file returned. 2) How do I still get the output of the function a and b?

Comment: Question 1 solved with your edit. Can just do a if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0) between the uigetfile and run lines. Thanks!

Comment: @Ayshaya sorry i was editing the answer. Well checks were not in the question, but you can easily check for that with a try catch statement. Also I did not realise the mfile was the filename() in your example. I thought it was just a script, not a function. I'll have to put some thought into this

Comment: Just to clear things out: your mfile is a function which has no inputs, but two outputs (a and b). Is that right? If so you are better of turning it into a script, removing the function call line, and your problem is solved

Comment: Yes, no inputs and some outputs (actually over a dozen, just simplified for posting). I'm not sure I follow? Remove the function call line?

Comment: If you have no inputs, your function is essentialy a script. When you run a script you don't need to bother assigning output or input variables during the call (hence my solution) ,while a with a function you do. So if you run a script your dozen outputs will be directly available to the workspace, and my solution will work for you. It will be much simpler than the alternatives I am considering if you need to pass the output variables (a and b in the example) during the function call.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answer and accepted but you might want to look at:

```
output = feval ( str2func ( filename(1:end-2) ) )
```

The (1:end-2) is to remove the .m

This way you can store the output of your function in the variable **output**.   If your m-files have variable number of outputs you could store them in a struct or a cell array.

Just because a function has no inputs - I would not consider that the **same** as a script - your "script" could overwrite a lot of variables in your calling function and you wouldn't know... -> and thus it would be a nightmare to debug...

Comment: I'd recommend using [fileparts](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) rather than `1:end-2` to get the file name without extension. More robust to longer file extensions beyond the traditional 3 characters.